Tangent to the graph of $y = x^3 +x + 16$ passes through the origin. Find the tangent of the angle of inclination of this tangent to the axis oX.
The tangent to the graph of the function $y = x^3 + x + 16$ passes through the origin. Find the tangent of the angle of inclination of this tangent to the axis of the abscissa.
As far as I understand, you need to use the tangent equation here: $y = x^3 + x + 16 \;\;O(0;0)$. $y' = 3x^2+1;\;\;\;y-f(x_0) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0);\;\;\;2a^3+16 = 0$;$\;\;\;a=-2$
$f'(-2) = 13 \Rightarrow tg\alpha = 13$.
Is my reasoning correct?

Hint: since your tangent passes through the origin, its equation can be written as $y= f'(x_0)x$.

Sorry, the way you wrote the question is confusing(to me). Did you mean: "Find the tangent of the angle of inclination of a tangent to the curve
$=x^3+x+16$ If yes, start by differentiating y with respect to x and put x=0. The angle of inclination is given by $\tan(\theta)=m$ where $m$ is the gradient

@Svyat_Smirnov: Try to see if the tangent is $y=13x$ and explain why.
